Code completions in dap-debug-repl
I was wondering how I get the dap debug repl to perform code completions, say, for user defined variables and methods?
GNU Emacs     v29.4            
Doom core     v3.0.0-pre
Doom modules  v24.04.0-pre
(python +lsp +conda +pyright)
debugpy v1.8.7

